# HTML component moves will using slideToggle

Tags: jquery, html, css

When i click on a Class Section (div), i need to display section detail as slide Toggle. its working fine as expected, but when i click the section, its slide-down but the other component is mis-aligning (Age range component is moving to left side), so i thought of show the slide Toggle on top of the component. I used `z-index` which did not solve my problem.

Please refer the JsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/LccuM/

My code :

```
<div>
    <div style="width:550px;">
        <br>  
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" value="" style="width: 208px;" /> 
        <button type="button">send</button>  
        <br><br><br><br>
    </div>

    <div style="float: right; margin-top:-95px; width: 100px; " class="stdSection" >
        <a>Class Section</a> 
        <fieldset class="section" style="display:none; float:right; width:200px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="sec" value="1" />1<br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="sec" value="2" />2<br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="sec" value="3" />3<br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="sec" value="4" />4 <br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="sec" value="5" />5<br />
        </fieldset>
    </div>

    <div style="float: right; margin-top:-39px; padding-right: 25px; ">
        <span>Age : 5</span>
        <input type="range" name="points" min="5" max="18">
        <span>18</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div.stdSection').click(function() { 
        $(this).find('.section').slideToggle('slow');
    });
});
```

I don't want the Age range component should be moved, when im viewing my slide-toggle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below css to make it position proper

```
**CSS**
.section {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 200px;
    z-index: 1000;
}
.slider {z-index:1;}
```

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LccuM/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Z-index is not the issue. you need to overlap your div on that component [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/LccuM/2/)

```
background:#FFF;
display: block;
position: absolute;
right: 15px;
width: 200px;
```

set this css for your fieldset.

Comment: Thanks for your post @Era, Your solution also solve my problem, But still Rakesh answers first. So i had given u +1upvote. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @Hariharan: thats your choice, but always write your CSS in optimized way and as per Rakesh, `float:right` and `position:absolute` cant be there for one div.

Comment: Sure @Era... I wont take entire code. i will take only my mistake and trying to write in optimal way as you suggest. Thanks for your support.